# Google Cloud Compute MongoDB Deployment security issue and keyFile issue

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've ran into this super annoying issue today.

Basically, I have setup a MongoDB database using the GCP Marketplace offering. It sets up a primary node, secondary, and an arbiter. Which is super cool.
What it doesn't do is security. Like, at all. So only natural I had to set it up myself. Well, now 20 hours later and a few good punches to my own face I am still struggling to get it running.

Basically, this is my partial config:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: '/etc/mongodKey'
```

If I comment out the `keyFile` the instance runs. But it cannot connect to any other nodes, because of the security being enabled. And no, I cannot disable it, are you mad?

The thing about the keyFile though... As I understand, `mongod` cannot open it, so it won't start. I suppose `/etc` is not a good place to put it in? I tried other folders, but to no avail. Nothing works.

And I need to have that security measure, since the database needs to be connected to by my colleagues using Robo 3T. So dropping the external IP address is out of the question.

What me do wrong? Please help as I'm pulling my own hair out.

This is the output of `sudo service mongod status`:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-08-21 15:28:08 UTC; 4min 29s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 1024 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1024 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Aug 21 15:28:08 m-vm-0 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Aug 21 15:28:08 m-vm-0 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/F
Aug 21 15:28:08 m-vm-0 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 21 15:28:08 m-0 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Edit:

I checked the `mongod.log`. Yes it is a permission issue. And I cannot solve it.

I tried doing `sudo chmod 400 /etc/mongodKey` but it doesn't do anything.
Please, someone, where do I put the key file so it is readable by mongodb? This is very important!

Comment: Ok, nvm. I got in trouble and then by accident I did `sudo chmod 600 /etc` and now I can't access that folder anymore. So the whole deployment is fucked and can't be fixed. Well, getting fired is not bad. I'll finally move onto doing something else. Fuck devops and fuck programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the GCP MongoDB marketplace deployment named "MongoDB", that allows you to setup replication, know the following:

They do not setup the security in the initial configuration, thus there are 2 options:

1. Turn off the External IP
2. Enable authorization in the `mongod.conf`

If you go for the first solution, you won't be able to easily connect to the database from any other external sources.

If you go for the second solution, you'll need to do the following:

1. Generate a key, the whole process can be found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/
2. Copy the file contents
3. SSH into all of your Compute Engine instances
4. Choose a directory
5. `sudo touch <path to key>`
6. `sudo nano <path to key>`
7. Paste the key you generated on your computer and save
8. `sudo chmod 600 <path to key>`
9. `sudo chown mongodb: <path to key>`
10. Update your `mongod.conf` which is found under `/etc/mongod.conf`
11. Uncomment `security`, `authorization`, `keyFile`
12. Provide the path under key `keyFile` to your keyfile
13. Stop all instances and start them again

Now MongoDB has access to the keyfile.

What as nightmare. And `chmod 400 <path to key>` didn't work for me as specified in the documentation. I had to set it to `chmod 600 <path to key>`.